# As a gentile how can I know if I am going to hell according to Judaism?

Tags: afterlife

As a gentile, how can I know if I am going to hell according to Judaism? I have no idea, being much more familiar with Buddhism and Christianity.

For what it's worth, I'm more or less atheist, have good will for most, and am morally upright I believe.

Comment: A gentile will be judged according to the *seven commandments of Noah*. The idea of a *nonbeliever* being automatically sent to hell is only a Christian concept. Do a google search of the *seven commandments of Noah*

Comment: A non-Jew is judged based on their adherence to the [Seven Laws of Noah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Laws_of_Noah). There isn't "one" Jewish view on the concept of heaven and hell; like most things in Judaism, there are multiple opinions. The base line is that a person should live a life of good and shouldn't be overly concerned with what happens when we die. We know that God is a wise and just God, therefore if someone tries his best to live a moral life, God will judge them fairly.